# Kotlin pass string with escaped Dollar sign

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

In our project I want to pass string with dollar sign. Final result should look like this: `~ $1300`. But I get only `~` the rest is not print. By debugging I found out that the issue is the dollar sign. How I can pass strings with dollar sign? Escaping dollar sign not solving this problem.

```
fun setItem() {
   bind(valueSubtitle = "~ \$${trx.currencyAmount}")
        }
fun bind(valueSubtitle: String? = null) {
        val valueSubtitleTextView = findViewById(R.id.txtValueSubtitle)
        valueSubtitleTextView.text = valueSubtitle
    }
```

I don't have issues with direct printing string with dollar sign. I have issue when I try to pass this string to other function, and only then print it.

**Update**
I debugged, and found out that I have issue when my number has double zero at the end: `189.00 or 123.00`. These number causes the problem. Other number like `123.40 or 1152.90` shows correctly.

**Update 2**
Issue was with my TextView. It behaved strangely when it was printing different double numbers. It was solved when I changed `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-2425

Comment: why dont just concate like "$"+"${trx.currencyAmount}"

Comment: I wonder if your "Update 2" shouldn't rather be an answer (and then probably accepted)... the `\$` is no problem... the shown answers just show other approaches how a `$` could be set in a string. But no answer contains what solved your problem...  Funny enough: the accepted answer is basically just the same as what you have posted (but more complete in the sense that it also shows the activity).

Comment: You are damn right! (copyright: Heisenderg)

Answer (score 5):

You could try for a literal representation.

```
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val amount = "25"
    val escapedString = "~ ${'$'}$amount"
    printString(escapedString)

}

fun printString( str : String) {
    println(str)
}
```

Comment: Yes it works for printing to console. But setting this to TextView not working :(

Comment: @Rafael have you checked if you've an issue with textview, because that string syntax should work.

Comment: @Rafael I also checked with the textview and  it works

Comment: I checked my textview, it prints other stuff, but not these strings

Answer (score 1):

Templates are supported both inside *raw strings* and inside *escaped strings*. If you need to represent a literal **`$`** character in a raw string *(which doesn't support backslash escaping)*, you can use the following syntax:

```
itemAmount.bind(valueSubtitle = "~ \${'$'}${trx.currencyAmount}")
```

*Looks pretty bad syntax, but will work*.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val trx: Transaction = Transaction(1300.00)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setItem()
}

fun setItem() {
    bind(valueSubtitle = "~ \$${trx.currencyAmount}")
}

fun bind(valueSubtitle: String? = null) {
    val valueSubtitleTextView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textview)
    valueSubtitleTextView.text = valueSubtitle
}

  class Transaction(var currencyAmount: Double)
}
```

Comment: I don't have issues with direct printing string with dollar sign. I have issue when I try to pass this string to other function, and only then print it.

Comment: @Rafael Please see the updated answer. Its working for me

Comment: @Rafael Did it work? I tried with a TextView and it displays as expected

Comment: What is the type of `trx.currencyAmount`? can you post the full code? because the same code is working for me

Comment: trx.currencyAmount is Double

Comment: @Rafael Still it works. I'm updating the answer with my whole activity code. Please compare it with yours

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown. Note also that you can use several ways to escape the dollar sign and that in your specific case you wouldn't even need to escape it. Just compare with the following sample code:

```
data class Container(val amount : Double = 123.00)
fun main() { // used Kotlin 1.3
  val trx = Container()
  listOf("~ \$${trx.amount}", // your variant
         "~ $${trx.amount}", // easier and works too
         """~ $${trx.amount}""", // everything in this string must not be escaped
         "~ ${'$'}${trx.amount}", // actually you may only use this if you require something like shown below (e.g. if you want to print something like $none)
         """~ ${"$"}${trx.amount}""", // similar to the one before
         // variants to print $none:
         "~ \$none",
         "~ ${'$'}none",
         """~ ${'$'}none""",
         """~ $${""}none"""
      )
      .forEach(::println)
}
```

The output of the above is:

```
~ $123.0
~ $123.0
~ $123.0
~ $123.0
~ $123.0
~ $none
~ $none
~ $none
~ $none
```

But none of these answers were the solution to your problem. As the `$` in your code wasn't the problem as you found out yourself...

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val dollar = "~$"
    val amount = 1212
    println("${dollar}${amount}")
}
```